# What is star query optimization?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, query

I found in a features table for SQL Server 2005 a row named "Star query optimization" but it is not explained anywhere.

Could this be a feature that optimizes a query like :

```
SELECT * FROM Table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a business intelligence feature, allowing the query planner to make better decisions when performing queries on [star schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema) style databases, typically used in business intelligence / data warehouse implementations.

Some sparse background is available [in this blogs.msdn.com post](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlqueryprocessing/archive/2007/04/09/how-to-check-whether-the-final-query-plan-is-optimized-for-star-join.aspx), but the article they link to for deeper information is gone.